# Swift Protocol requiring a @Published Bool be defined

Tags: swift

I would like to declare a Swift protocol that requires conforming classes define a @Published Bool

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject, MyProtocol {
    @Published var myBool: Bool = false

    .
    .
}
```

My best shot at this is,

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var _myBool: Binding<Bool> { get set }
}
```

...but the compiler complains, "Cannot find type 'Binding' in scope"

In my case, the class implementing the protocol will define the Bool, so I don't want a shared implementation (extension), I just need to require the class to have its own.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your title and code doesn’t add up.

Comment: `@State`, `@Published`, and `Binding` are all different things, yet you seem to use them interchangeably

Comment: In any case, protocols currently cannot require a property wrapper. Here's a [longer discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/property-wrapper-requirements-in-protocols/33953) around a proposal to introduce it.